# Alligator population

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Hints only. I feel like I am so close. Population growth: The time rate change of an alligator population $P$ in a swamp is proportional to the square of $P$. The swamp contained a dozen alligators in $1988$ and $2$ dozen in $1998$

$$\frac{dp}{dt} = kp^2$$

$$\int \frac{dp}{p^2} = \int k$$

$$ \frac{p^{-2+1}}{-2+1} = tk + C$$

$$ -\frac{1}{p} = tk+C$$

Use $P(0) = 12$ to solve for C.

$$-\frac{1}{12} = C$$

$$p(t) = -\frac{1}{tk - \frac{1}{12}}$$

Use $P(10)=24$ to solve for k:

$$24 = -\frac{1}{10k-\frac{1}{12}}$$

$$10k -\frac{1}{12} = -\frac{1}{24}$$

$$k = \frac{1}{240}$$

Now solve for $t$ with $P(t)=48$

$$48=-\frac{1}{\frac{t}{240}-\frac{1}{12}}$$

$$\frac{t}{240} - \frac{1}{12} = -\frac{1}{48}$$

$$\frac{t}{20}-1=-3$$

$$\frac{t}{20}=-2$$

$$t=-40$$

Which is obviously wrong. I assume that t should in-fact represent 1 year even though our information is given in increments of 10. I am very sure my set-up is correct and I integrated correctly...

Comment: You have made a mistake solving the linear equation at the end: when multiplying $-\frac{1}{48}\times12\neq-3$

Comment: Okay thankyou I got 15 which is the correct answer in the back of the book i believe. It gives a function rather than 15 but plugging in 48 gave me 15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have correctly derived that

$$P(t) = -\frac{1}{tk - \frac{1}{12}}\tag{1}$$

and

$$k = \frac{1}{240}\tag{2}$$

so that

$$P(t) = -\frac{1}{\frac{t}{240} - \frac{1}{12}}\tag{3}$$

Your mistake happens when solving for $P(t)=48$. Starting off at

$$48=-\frac{1}{\frac{t}{240}-\frac{1}{12}}\implies\frac{t}{240} - \frac{1}{12} = -\frac{1}{48}$$

is correct. However

$$\frac{t}{240} - \frac{1}{12} = -\frac{1}{48}\implies \frac{t}{20}-1=-3$$

is incorrect. Multiplying all three terms by $12$ would produce

$$\frac{t}{240} - \frac{1}{12} = -\frac{1}{48}\implies \frac{t}{20}-1=-\frac{1}{4}$$

which you could then multiply again by $20$ to form

$$\frac{t}{20}-1=-\frac{1}{4}\implies t-20=5$$

so that $t=15$.